# Link Item Collection in n2cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2cms, episerver-6

I used EpiServer CMS. I'm just wondering if n2cms has any attribute to collect links. (like LinkItemCollection in EpiServer). If not, Please give me an idea to implement.

Reference: http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/Developers%20Guide/Core%20Features/Properties/How%20To/Use%20Link%20Collection%20property.htm
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `ContentList` part and creating a bunch of redirect pages. This is best if you want to re-use the collection of links again and again.

1. Create a dummy placeholder page somewhere, and make it invisible.
2. Under that placeholder page, create a Redirect page for each link.
3. Where you want the collection of links to appear, drag & drop a `ContentList` and point the root at the dummy placeholder page. You can then write a custom HTML template to display the link however you like.

One other idea would be to use N2CMS `Selection` part, which gives you a checkbox list of all the pages in your site. You simply check the ones you want to list, and `Selection` will format a list of all the pages you checked.

With both of these methods, if you link to other pages in your site, N2 will offer to update links for you if you rename any of the target pages (as long as they're in the same N2 site).

All of this is documented in the N2CMS documentation here: https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/N2CMS/Linking+to+Content?src=search

Look under the heading *Dynamically Linking to Content Items*